Get x or y distance between 2 items in a 2D array[,] of any type not knowing the index of either items and edit items in between
For learning purposes I'm asking "any type" but I actually got a byte[,] type array I'm working on right now, it's called byteTable and its content looks like this:
 00  01  E1  03  04  05

 06  07 (08) 09  0A  0B

 08  0D  0E  0F  10 (08)

 12  13  14  15  04  17

(08) 19 {1A} 1B  1C  1D

 1E  1F  20  10 (08) 23

The parentheses are there only for readability's sake. I'd like to find the index of the unique 1A byte in the array, then find the nearest non-unique 08 byte value in vertical-up direction from 1A and get its distance. After that, I needed to replace all the bytes in between with FF bytes, including the 1A byte but not the 08 byte, then repeat this operation clockwise from the byte where 0E used to be.
Alternatively, rather than finding the distance, maybe overwrite all bytes until a 08 byte is reached, following a clockwise movement starting vertically from 1A. Whichever method is more feasible?
The result should look like this:

 00  FF  E1  03  04  05

 06  FF  08  09  0A  0B

 08  FF  FF  FF  FF  08

 12  FF  FF  15  FF  17

 08  FF  FF  FF  FF  1D

 1E  1F  20  10  08  23


did I explain the problem in a way that's hard to understand? let me know if you need more details please

You can't cast from a byte[,] to a Matrix[,] and it's probably not what you want either. A Matrix is a 4x4 table (never more, never less), so you probably would want to do var matrix = (Matrix)byteTable; but that won't work either, for the reason that you can't simply cast an array to a Matrix.

I would remove the Matrix stuff from your question, it's irrelevant. Also, my above statement was wrong, Systems.Windows.Media.Matrix is actually a 3x3 table.

ok never mind the matrix

I see FFs where they should not be according to your description. E.g. the 01 and 07 (top left) are not in the direction of a 08. How exactly are you moving? Are you moving only horizontally or also in diagonals? What are the rules for when there is not 08 in the considered direction. What are the stop conditions?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes check the image link

yes there isn't a 08 byte as I was mentioning in the second part of the post, if it's possible to go straight until a 08 is met following a clockwise movement, rather than telling it to go in direction of the 08, it would be good too, whichever way is more realistic

thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm not allowed to embed images yet or so the editor was saying ^^

What's the original question?

@shingo just like the title says but since the result would be the same with either methods I described in the post, I let you choose what you think is better, I'm only an amateur after all so I trust experienced devs more than my problem resolving skills, so if you can think of a method even better than both possible ways I described then I will gladly listen

You have 4 "modes"; and one follows the other: (moving) up; right; down; left; up (again); etc. A "state machine" of your array would be able to: find the starting point; "sample" or move according to the current mode. "Sampling" an "08" triggers a mode change from the previous. As one move "off" a current "square", if it's not "FF", set it to "FF". I assume the game is over when one runs "off the board"; though you could wind up with a "cycle".

Thanks everyone for your input, I will be practicing with what I learned from this thread for now. Also for people winding up here from the title: I will add a part to the op about the distance issue, I'm sure it will be useful to someone some day.

First you will have to find the 2d index of the 1A byte. Then, you need to iterate your index until you find a 08 byte, turn it, and repeat until you hit the edge of your array.
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    // Find index of an element in a 2d array
    public static (int x, int y) CoordinateOf<T>(this T[,] array, T value)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); ++y)
            {
                if (array[x, y]?.Equals(value) == true)
                    return (x, y);
            }
        }

        return (-1, -1);
    }

    // Do the Stuff op asked
    public static void DoStuff(this byte[,] array)
    {
        // Declare variables
        var pos = array.CoordinateOf<byte>(0x1A);
        var dir = (x: -1, y: 0); // Because 2d arrays are weird, this is 'up'
        var width = array.GetLength(0);
        var height = array.GetLength(1);

        // Move the position an initial step
        pos.x += dir.x;
        pos.y += dir.y;

        // Cache the starting position
        var start = pos;

        // Loop until we cross the edge of the array
        while (pos.x >= 0 && pos.x < width
            && pos.y >= 0 && pos.y < height)
        {
            if (array[pos.x, pos.y] == 0x08)
            {
                // If the element is 0x08, turn clockwise
                pos.x -= dir.x;
                pos.y -= dir.y;

                dir = (dir.y, -dir.x);
            }
            else
                array[pos.x, pos.y] = 0xFF; // Set 0xFF

            // Add direction to position
            pos.x += dir.x;
            pos.y += dir.y;

            if (pos.x == start.x && dir.x == 0
                && pos.y == start.y && dir.y == -1)
                break; // prevent infinite loop
        }
    }
}


What operation is (-1, -1) performing on the result, at return (-1, -1);? About this other part: if (array[pos.x, pos.y] == 0xFF) is it stopping the loop at FF? it's fine if FF gets overwritten by another FF though.

(-1, -1) is a Tuple. They are very useful in your use case. But for all intends and purposes: (-1, -1) are 2 ints wrapped into an anonymous object. It would be "the same" (not really but whatevs) as creating a struct with 2 ints x & y.

As for stopping the loop when it hits a FF, that's because if you have 4 08's in a circle your program will loop forever. Since your example didn't have any FF's in its table I assumed it would be fine, but if you want to support the case where FF's may already exist, I would need to make a small change.

More about tuples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

It now checks if you've reached your starting position and -direction again, ergo we are infinitely looping, ergo we need to call break. Tables with initial FF values are now possible.

Thank you Casey, the more I learn about arrays and loops, the more I like C#. A lot of ideas coming to mind, whether I will be able to identify what to use and where it's a different matter though^^

did you use an AI code generator? I've been trying to debug this code for hours but it just keeps throwing errors

No problem, happy to help. Yesterday was a slow day anyway :p
Don't forget to check the answer you accept, and upvote all the ones you like! It's how knowledge gets shared and discovered on stackoverflow :)

I have definitely not used AI, but I also haven't checked it thoroughly. What error are you getting?
btw the way I've written it, make sure to either put the whole thing in a static class, or remove the 'this' keyword from the array parameter in both methods.

There were still a few issues, I've solved them now. IndexOf was a bad name for my extension method as it already exists (duh, dumb of me) and I forgot to add "void" in front of "DoStuff()". There was also an issue with the direction. Because 2D arrays and their representation are a bit weird, 'up' in this case turned out to be x: -1, y: 0

Since you are learning, rather than giving you the full solution, I will give you some hints.

You can use two nested for loops to find the 1A value. One loop loops over x, the other over y. It is easier to implement this in a separate function, because then you can simply use the return statement to stop looping and return the result.
You can return the x- and y-indexes with a tuple: (int x, int y).
See: Tuple types (C# reference)

You need a way to define the four cardinal directions. A possible way is to declare delta x and y values for the moving direction in an array of tuples like this (I am defining the positive y direction downwards. If you do it the other way round you must change the signs of the dy):
//                                 up     right    down    left
(int dx, int dy)[] directions = [(0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0)];

Then you can cycle the directions with the modulo operator % to limit the index like this
int direction = 0; // upwards

// In the main loop
(int dx, int dy) = directions[direction];
direction = (direction + 1) % 4;

You would use this code in a main loop to determine the direction and use a nested inner loop to perform the movement in a straight line by adding dx and dy to x and y respectively.
The inner loop ends when you either reach a border or a 08.
The main loop ends when you reach a border which depends on the moving direction. E.g. when dx is -1 then x == 0 is a border, when dx = 1 then x == width_of_the_array - 1 is a border, etc.
Of course you can determine this condition in a classic way with a lengthy Boolean expression or a series of if-statements, or you could use a very advanced technique using Lambda expressions.
For this we would expand the tuple of the directions array by a delegate representing the border condition:
(int dx, int dy, Func<int, int, bool> isBorder)[] directions = [
    ( 0, -1, (ix, iy) => iy <= 0),
    ( 1,  0, (ix, iy) => ix >= Width - 1),
    ( 0,  1, (ix, iy) => iy >= Height - 1),
    (-1,  0, (ix, iy) => ix <= 0)
];

You can then get the direction dependent parameters with
var (dx, dy, isBorder) = directions[direction];

Then you can check the border condition with if (isBorder(x, y)) { ... }.
This means that you don't need to calculate a distance, you just loop until you reach a condition. E.g.
while (true) { // endless inner loop
    if (byteTable[x, y] == 0x08) {
        break; // end the inner loop and let the outer loop turn around clockwise
    }
    byteTable[x, y] = 0xFF;
    if (a border is reached) {
        return; // end the algorithm and print out the solution.
    }
}


You also asked about allowing any array element type. C# has so called generics. See: Generic classes and methods.
They allow you to replace the real type by a generic type. E.g. you could wrap your solution in a generic method:
public static void Solve<T>(T[,] table, T uniqueStartValue, T wayMark)
{
    // where wayMark corresponds to the 08 byte
    ...
}

Note that you can't apply a == b to generic types. You would have to compare two values with a.Equals(b).

I admit that I used a lot of very advanced stuff. But you can of course use a simpler approach involving more code. Instead of using the directions array (with tuples and lambdas) you would write four distinct pieces of code for each of the four cardinal directions.
Also, you don't need to find a solution for everything from start. Advance in small steps and slowly improve the solution until everything works. Assuming that this is a Console application, a PrintTable(byteTable) method is very useful not only to print the final result but also for debugging to print intermediate states within a loop, so that you can watch how the algorithms proceeds (and where it  fails).

First time reading about Generics. I think I used tuples in the past without knowing it, I'll test them both thoroughly anyway.
